# how to make a runnable jar for a java project with properties files will be editable at runtime?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jar

My maven project is a standalone java appplication. I need to run this form a Unix box. So i made a runnable jar.But i have to update a date in the *app.properties* file in every run.I tried maven jar plugin to make a fatty runnable jar with all dependency. It is running fine , but not able to edit the *app.properties* file

Comment: You cannot edit a file that is in the jar. You need to program it so that it extracts the file from the jar to a file, if the file doesn't already exist, and then always use the file rather than the jarred version. And then you can edit the file.

Comment: You might consider using the [java.util.prefs.Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read a properties file from the classpath (root package) like this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/app.properties")));
```

You can start a runnable jar with a custom classpath like this:

```
java -cp app.properties:app.jar my.main.AppClass
```

(you cannot use `java -jar` because then the `-cp` option is ignored)

Put the file `app.properties` in the same directory as `app.jar`. The location of `app.properties` will be the first entry on the classpath and thus the code in the jar can load it as shown above.

If you make sure there is also a copy of `app.properties` in the jar, then that will be used as default if the external properties file is missing. (note that this only works for the complete properties file, not for individual properties)